# Checking Node App Console Output Live on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, console

I'm currently have a problem with a post request my node app is getting from my ios app acting as the client. This only occurs when the node app is live on heroku. It works perfectly find in the localhost. So I want to know if there is a way to check the console logs when the app is live. I know about heroku run -t but I want to actually see the console output to see what the heck is going on differently between the localhost and the live app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `heroku logs -t -a yourapp` to see live tail of heroku logs.

The papertrail addon is also very nice, it gives you a nice log tail view that you can apply searches & filters on. `heroku addons:add papertrail:choklad`

Loggly is another great option. You don't have the live tail view but their search and filtering capabilities are fantastic. https://www.loggly.com/

Comment: I tried the first option and im getting heroku router info. Now is there a way to get the actual console output from the post request sent? I'm getting this: at=info method=GET path="/api/signup" host=www.themobimall.com request_id=8aab35a1-606b-4d71-83de-0294955a9c36 fwd="174.32.171.125" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=121

Comment: Sure, anything your node app sends to stdout will show up in your heroku tail. That includes `console.log`, but if you want to log details for each request incoming for example you can use https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

Comment: I included the morgan module and added the statement: app.use(morgan('combined')). I'm getting new output in the heroku logs but it's still doesn't include the console.log(req.body) statement in my node  post route. Instead, its just info about the iphone simulator. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might try `console.log` something at app startup, and then `heroku ps:restart` to make sure it's actually working. You might also try adding a string in front of your body log, eg `console.log('body:', req.body)` to make sure req.body is non empty. Beyond that, I think I would need to see your code and your Procfile to help any further.